# I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 as a dual boot but wifi adapter is not found

Tags: ubuntu, iwlwifi

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 as a dual boot but wifi adapter is not found.

Laptop: Maingear-Element

Mainboard: Intel

Adapter: Intel® WiFi 6 AX 200 (2.4GHz/5GHz)

**lspci output:**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1b.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #14 (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #15 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM470 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106M [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1)
01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB Type-C UCSI Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
03:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
04:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
06:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
3c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation SSD 660P Series (rev 03)
3d:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
3e:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
```

**lsusb output:**

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0316 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0-CRW
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 048d:ce00 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device(8291)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b68b Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HD Webcam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: can you provide some information about the laptop/mainboard/wifiadapter you are using? (use the edit-function of the question to provide this information)

Comment: I updated my wifi driver in windows, now the wifi is working in ubuntu

Comment: Sometimes when I boot into ubuntu wifi adapter is not found, whereas sometimes it's working ok. I have made sure the secure boot is off, but still, it keeps on happening. Can anyone help me!

Comment: It is working if you reboot from windows into linux but not, when you boot directly into linux? the you have the firmware-files for your adapter missing.

Comment: No, it does not matter if I reboot from windows or directly. Also, firmware-files are there.

Comment: I rebooted from windows and now wifi is working. I don't know why sometimes the wifi will work and sometimes not.

Comment: @blaimi you were right. When I restart from windows to ubuntu the wifi works, but if I log on to ubuntu directly the wifi is not working. Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

As we pointed out with the comments:

You are missing the firmware-files for your adapter. The firmware should be contained in the package `linux-firmware` since version 1.182 ([changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.182/changelog)), focal has 1.187. I'm wondering why this is not working, because the package should be installed by default. Alternatively you can download the firmware directly from [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless.html) and place the to /lib/firmware.

More about firmware and ubuntu in the [ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Firmware).